# How to replace multiple sub occurrences of string

Tags: regex, go

I have one use case where I can have a text string which can contain anything. What I want to achieve is to replace a certain pattern within that given string.

Let's say I have given string as

```
:es1
es2
aaes1aa
:es3,
es1:
ees1,
ees1 

{
"es1 :
```

What I am trying to do is here is suppose I have to replace all es1 in this string but with one condition. It has to be either end or start with `[, | ; | : | " | ' | \\ | \s]`. `:es1`, `es1,`, `es1:` and so on are accepted but `eees1sss` is not.

I tried `([, | ; | : | " | ' | \\ | \s])(es1)([, | ; | : | " | ' | , | \s])` something like this but I don't think it's what I need.

Go program:

```
match := regexp.MustCompile(`([, | ; | : | " | ' | \\ | \s])(es1)([, | ; | : | " | ' | , | \s])`)
    test := `:es1
    es2
    aaes1aa
    :es3,
    es1:
    ees1,
    ees1 
    
    {
    "es1 :`
    
    fmt.Println(match.ReplaceAllString(test, "$1es4$3"))
```

output:

```
       es2
        aaes1aa
        :es3,
:
        ees1,
        ees1 

        {
         :
```

I was expecting my output to be more like

```
:es4
    es2
    aaes1aa
    :es3,
    es4:
    ees1,
    ees1 

    {
    "es4 :
```

Comment: What about `e:es1`?

Comment: should match. since there is a delimiter in the back of es1. but only if e:es1 ends with one of delimiter as well or is last character in the string

Comment: first word and last are also allowed. es1: or :es1 in text `es1: .....some text. ..:es1`

Answer (score 2):

the solution provided below is not well tested against all possibilities, but it seems to be working.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    match := regexp.MustCompile(`([, | ; | : | " | ' | \\ | \s])es1|^es1([, | ; | : | " | ' | , | \s])`)
    test := `:es1
    es2
    aaes1aa
    :es3,
    es1:
    ees1,
    ees1 
    
    {
    "es1 :`

    fmt.Println(match.ReplaceAllString(test, "${1}es4${2}"))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/E8lb9vmM_Sa

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    match := regexp.MustCompile(`([,;:"'\\\s])es1\b|\bes1([,;:"'\\\s])`)
    test := ":es1\n    es2\n    aaes1aa\n    :es3,\n    es1:\n    ees1,\n    ees1 \n    \n    {\n    \"es1 :"
    fmt.Println(match.ReplaceAllString(test, "${1}es4$2"))
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/7q_KDyOjDcj) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LsURMU/1). Note that the spaces and `|` chars inside square brackets are meaningful and match these chars literally, thus, you need to remove them all from your pattern.

The regex matches:

- `([,;:"'\\\s])es1\b` - Group 1: a comma, or a semi-colon, colon, double or single quotation mark, backslash or whitespace; then `es1` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `|` - or
- `\bes1` - a whole word `es1`
- `([,;:"'\\\s])` - Group 2: a comma, or a semi-colon, colon, double or single quotation mark, backslash or whitespace